# Оптимизация в python

Tags: python, алгоритм, циклы

Скажите, если ли преимущество у такой реализации:

```
count = 1
for i in range(0, count_tests):
    count = 1
    while True:
        if random() > 0.3333333333333333333333:
            res[i] += 1
            break
        count += 1
```

перед такой:

```
for i in range(0, count_tests):
    count = 1
    while True:
        if random() > 0.3333333333333333333333:
            res[i] += 1
            break
        count += 1
```

Поясню: в первом случае мы создаём переменную до цикла, а в цикле каждый раз просто обновляем значения. Во втором случае переменная объявлена в цикле. В Java, например, первый вариант будет выигрышнее. Хотелось бы узнать, как на питоне

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что первый вариант будет выигрышнее?

Comment: В джаве, например, мы бы не пересоздавали ссылку на переменную каждую итерацию цикла. Конечно, за меня это, скорее всего оптимизировал бы компилятор, но говнокодить не хочется

Comment: В джаве это не было бы ссылкой, это ведь простой тип, а не Integer. (если не верите: https://habr.com/post/104231/) А смысл `count = 1` перед циклом, чтобы сразу же на первой итерации повторить присваивание? Точнее, смысл проявится если `count` после цикла где-то используется, тогда при `count_tests` меньшим или равным 0, для второго алгоритма будет ошибка при выполнении

Comment: В питоне нет переменных. Любое присваивание связывает имя со значением.

Comment: У вас вопрос чисто академический или вы пытаетесь оптимизировать данный кусок кода? Во втором случае стоит пояснить что вы пытаетесь сделать. Наверняка вам предложат более быстрый/оптимальный вариант если будет понятна задача/цель

Comment: вопрос по большей части академический